# Add Namespace to anonymous xml

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I am trying to add a namespace to an input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VLOG_Export>
  <Send_Referenznr_01>3200000042</Send_Referenznr_01>
  <Send_Referenznr_06>00000000001000189718</Send_Referenznr_06>
  <Send_ID>1Z78A1070461454103</Send_ID>
</VLOG_Export>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:VLOG_Export xmlns:ns0="http://mycomp.com/VLOG/SD/vlog/export">
   <Send_Referenznr_01>sdfsdf</Send_Referenznr_01>
   <Send_Referenznr_06>sdfsf</Send_Referenznr_06>
   <Send_ID>sdfsdf</Send_ID>
</ns0:VLOG_Export>
```

Using this xslt :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://mycomp.com/VLOG/SD/vlog/export">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the wrong output.
Any tips welcome.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://mycomp.com/VLOG/SD/vlog/export">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/VLOG_Export" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyz